# Displaying multiple profile data on a page using PHP and MySQLi

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am trying to display different profiles on a page by using PHP and MySQLi. My    expectation is to show the data in rectangles. Each profile data including a small photo should be enclosed in a rectangle. The profiles should be generated using the data from the database. Please refer the image for the expected result. Kindly suggest some good approach to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GazVu.jpg)

Comment: Do you have any constructed view for that? You must create a view first in order to fill that with data.

Comment: No. I have not created any view yet. I was waiting for an idea. Thanks to you for suggesting me.